# why does uninstalling python keep the install directory

Tags: python, windows, installation, uninstallation

I used to use Python 3.8 32-bit but I recently uninstalled it and got the 64-bit version instead.

Strangely, uninstalling it left the install directory, which was
`%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Python38-32`.

The 32-bit version still has the site-packages, scripts folder, and a few others.

The contents are:

```
Python38-32
|
|--- include
|       |_pygame
|          |_<some C/C++ header files here>
|--- Lib
|      |_site-packages
|         |_<insert site packages here>
|      struct.pyo
|--- Scripts
|       |_<stuff here>
|--- share
|      |_doc
|         |_<empty directory>
```

Is it safe to delete the `Python38-32` folder?

Note: I am using Windows.

Also: I wasn't sure whether to post this on superuser or StackOverflow because it is python related. Please tell me if I need to post it on superuser and I will move the question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you can safely remove that folder after uninstallation. In case you have some projects that point to the removed 32-bit Python, you can modify it so that they point to the correct 64-bit one.

You may also want to check your Windows system path to make sure the path to the 32-bit version is not included, and the path to the 64-bit version is included.